# XSD restriction of element with inheritance doesn't work

Tags: xml, xsd, restriction, complextype

I'm trying inherit and restrict an element but I'm getting following error (in eclipse validation):

> The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle
>   of the base.

The "Description" element should not be part of the "TypeDevice" element. I just can't get it why. This should be possible (according to this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-flexschema/)):

Can anyone help me?

Greets,

Bill

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com" xmlns="http://www.example.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <!--  Abstract Base Class  -->
  <xs:complexType name="AbstractDevice" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <!--  Inheritance with restriction  -->
  <xs:complexType name="TypeDevice">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="AbstractDevice">                                
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:restriction>                        
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="TypeRoot">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Device" type="TypeDevice" />
    </xs:sequence>                
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Configuration" type="TypeRoot" />
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `AbstractDevice` has two required elements, whereas type `TypeDevice` has only one. Thus `TypeDevice` is not a valid instance of its base type `AbstractDevice`. In order to make it valid, you should add `minOccurs="0"` to `Description` element or turn the derivation around and use extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I thought, this was exactly what can be done with a restriction applied to an element. The linked tutorial does exactly this (restrict an element "Author" of the base type "Book" in the derived elment "Pamphlet" by restriction. Maybe I do misunderstand something here. By the way, it's not possible in my implementation to set Description to "minOccurs=0" in the base element.